# Access app permissions programatically in j2me

Tags: java-me, jar, permissions

I know I can set permissions of a j2me application before launching it ask first time or whatever for SMS, Read and Write. What I want to do is how can I access these options after launching the application from inside the app (no matter yet my app is not signed). I just want to get access to these permissions pragmatically, I tried to see few examples but they differ a lot, does anybody know about this? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out that it's not possible to get permissions settings inside J2me application, the best and only solution is to SIGN your application and on start it will ask for permissions.