# Change app permissions on Nokia 500

Tags: symbian

I have nokia 500 and I want to change the permissions for app permanently to connect to the internet so I wont need to allow it every time I open the app. How to do this? (sorry for bad English)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose its J2ME you are using, and not Symbian C++, Qt or WRT. Basically that phone did indeed have multiple developer offerings you could use for development.

And For Java, you could see couple of olde posts with similar issue, f.ex: [How to set permissions of my j2me app to “Always allowed” on S40 devices?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7711424/how-to-set-permissions-of-my-j2me-app-to-always-allowed-on-s40-devices), or [Access app permissions programatically in j2me](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13854657/access-app-permissions-programatically-in-j2me?rq=1). So basically the answer is that you would need to Sign your application.